# How do I execute a callback only if a specific attribute on the object changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a `Stock` model that has the following callback:

`after_save :update_port_stock_current_price`

But I only want that executed if the `Stock` object being saved had the price changed.

How do I detect if a specific attribute, i.e. `stock.price` has changed in this save?

Comment: after_save :update_port_stock_current_price, if: -> {self.price_changed?}

Comment: @Rohan that does work...as does the `ActiveRecord::DirtyModel` stuff in the link to the other SO question that @sawa indicated.